# Proofs Involving Law of Large Numbers

Tags: probability, law-of-large-numbers

I am learning about [*Moments*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_(mathematics)) in the context of Probability

- For some given probability distribution function the **theoretical** $k$-th moment is given by : $$\int_{\mathbb R} x^k \cdot f(x) \mathrm{d}x$$
- Given some measurements $x_1, x_2... x_n$  - regardless of our assumption on their probability distribution, the **sample** $k$-th moment is given by: $$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^k$$

**My Question:** I have often heard people (informally) say that when the number of measurements increases in size, the sample moment converges to the theoretical moment - but I have never seen a mathematical proof for this.

Is it possible to prove that :

$$ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^k \xrightarrow{} \int_{\mathbb R} x^k \cdot f(x) \mathrm{d}x $$

Thanks!

Comment: It is just Law of Large Numbers.

Comment: @ geetha290krm: thank you so much for your reply! If you have time, can you please show me how I can use the Law of Large Numbers to prove this?

Comment: If $(x_i)$ is i.i.d. so is $(g(x_i))$ for any (measurable) function $g$. Take $g(x)=x^{k}$.

Answer (score 2):

As hinted by geetha290krm in the comments, $X_i$ iid implies $X^k_i$ are iid.

The (weak) LLN states:

$$\frac1n \sum{Y_i} \xrightarrow{p} E[Y_i] \text{ as }n\to\infty,\; Y_i\text{ are iid}$$

Here, we let $Y_i=X_i^k$, and assuming the moments exist, we apply the LLN above to show convergence of sample moment to the theoretical moment.

Comment: @ Annika: thank you so much for your answer! I was just wondering - why is it so easy to apply LLN here?

Comment: BTW - do you enjoy probability theory? lately I have been thinking about and working on some probability brain teasers - would you be interested in looking at them?

Comment: @stats_noob -- yeah, probability is a favorite -- happy to look

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4739218/if-you-go-fishing-everyday-what-is-the-probability-you-know-x-of-the-pond , https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4731910/how-to-create-a-mathematical-model-of-an-elevator , https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4735898/what-is-the-probability-of-knowing-someone-in-the-office

Comment: @ Annika: Did you find these brain teasers interesting? Currently, I am looking into simulation based approaches for these problems .... I am not sure if exact analytical solutions exist...

Comment: @stats_noob -- yes, very -- agree that simulation and numerical stuff good place to start to build intuition (thank goodness for computers :)

Comment: :) I would be curious to learn more from you! are you a PhD student in math? Btw here is my latest (embarrassing) question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4748560/understanding-the-relationship-between-measure-theory-and-probability-theory  haha

Comment: @stats_noob nope, no PhD -- take a look at MathOverflow -- that stuff is intense! Just a data scientist -- I was trained in Operations Research so it did get math-ier than the typical engineering degree FWIW. Frankly, just constantly learning new math and asking/answering questions on here is how to progress and get better.

Actually, I specifically credit this site (MSE) for the majority of my learning in math beyond college and the development (to the extend it has) of my mathematical maturity. I also really like math books with answers in the back :)

Comment: so great to hear! these websites (stackoverflow for computers, math) have been very useful for me as well!

Comment: @stats_noob re: "I was just wondering - why is it so easy to apply LLN here?" -- As noted by geetha290km, since your $X_i$ are iid, you can create a new sequence by applying a function $f$ to each $X_i$ to get a new iid sequence of random variables $f(X_i)$. However, they are still a sequence of iid variates so we can apply LLN just like before. In your case, $f(X_i)=X_i^k$.